# Merging two arrays in one line of ruby code in a particular structure

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays

```
default = ['0', '0', '0', '0'] # this is fixed
new = ['2', '3', ''] # it can be of many variants like ['', '1'] or 
                   # ['1', '', '', ''], but will never have 
                   # more than 4 elements
```

I want to get a resultant array from above two arrays as

```
['2', '3', '0', '0']
```

How to achieve it *one line* of *simple* ruby code? I can do it in multiple line or with the help of inject/reduce.

Comment: `default.zip(new).map { |e| e.map(&:to_i).inject(&:+) }.map(&:to_s)`

Comment: this is just a shortened version of oldergod's solution: `default.zip(new).map { |d, v| (d.to_i + v.to_i).to_s }`

Comment: @megas solution is almost same. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
default.zip(new).map { |d,n| (n.nil? or n.empty?) ? d : n }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails --

```
n = 4 # number of elements you need
n.times.map{|x| new[x].presence || default[x] }
```

If not

```
n = 4 # number of elements you need
n.times.map{|x| (new[x].nil? || new[x] == "") ? default[x] : new[x] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is replace blanks/nils in "new" array with corresponding values from "default" array

try this

```
 default.each_index.collect {|i| (new[i].nil? || new[i] == '') ? default[i] : new[i]}
```

This should work for any length of "default" array. The returned array will be of the same length as "default"